# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined" I am trying to make a User Form on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror, userform

I'm trying to make a userform to enter jewelry into a spreadsheet. I'm following this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZNPkcT4PKA.
I keep getting this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined" error message. ***Please Help!***

**Pictures**

[image: Error Message]

[image: Code for functions]

[image: User Form Pic]

**Code**

Functions Code

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Interface");
  ws.appendRow([rowData.ID,rowData.Description,rowData.Color,rowData.Num,rowData.Stock,rowData.Orderers]);

  return true;
}

function anotherFunc() {

  addNewRow({ ID: "Clip-On", Description: "Ew", Color: "Green", Num: "8", Stock: "5", Orderers: "Shannon" })

}
```

Userform/App Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>.
  <body>
  
  <div class="container">

    <div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="input-IDtag">ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-IDtag" >
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="input-Descriptiontag">Description</label>
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="input-Descriptiontag">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="input-Colortag">Color</label>
        <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="input-Colortag">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="input-Numtag">Num</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input-Numtag">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="input-Stocktag">Stock</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input-Stocktag">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="input-Orderers">Orderers</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-Ordererstag">
      </div>
      
    </div>

      
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"id ="mainButton">ADD</button>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
<script>

      function afterButtonClicked(){
        var ID = document.getElementById("input-IDtag");
        var Description = document.getElementById("input-Descriptiontag");
        var Color = document.getElementById("input-Colortag");
        var Num = document.getElementById("input-Numtag");
        var Stock = document.getElementById("input-Stocktag");
        var Orderers = document.getElementById("input-Ordererstag");
        var rowData = {ID: ID.value,Description: Description.value,Color: Color.value,Num: Num.value,Stock: Stock.value,Orderers: Orderers.value};
        google.script,run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData); 
        }

          function afterSubmit(e){
            var ID = document.getElementById("input-IDtag");
            ID.value = "";


          }

        document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Load User Form Code

```
function loadForm(){
  
const htmlForSidebar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("App");
const htmlOutput = htmlForSidebar.evaluate();

const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput);

}


function createMenu(){

const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const menu = ui.createMenu("Dazzle Menu");
menu.addItem("Show Add Item Menu","loadForm" );
menu.addToUi();

}

function onOpen(){

createMenu();


}
```

Comment: Yeah well it looks like rowData is undefined you need to define it.

Comment: This is a problem: `google.script,run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData); ` it should be `google.script.run.`

Comment: This `var ID = document.getElementById("input-IDtag");` should be `var ID = document.getElementById("input-IDtag").value;`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your code and found some issues:

1. In your error message, you executed a function in apps script that is meant to be executed by `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData)` in your html file. That makes the parameter of addNewRow(rowData) null and causes the property error.
2. Replace the comma with dot (.) on `google.script,run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData)` should be `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData)`. `run` is a property of `google.script`

Example:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it!